# Using Excel VBA, delete document link to pasted table in word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to create some VBA code in Excel. I have cells from the excel file pasted special in the word file. I want the code to open the word document, refresh the table, save it as a new doc referencing data in the excel file, then delete the pasted tables connection with the excel document. I have managed to do everything but the last part.

As of now, the file that it saves is still connected meaning any changes made to the excel document are reflected in ALL the word documents, which is an issue when I want the excel document to be a template that creates invoices.

```
Dim objWord As Object
Dim invno As Long
Dim custname As String
Dim amt As Currency
Dim dt_issue As Date
Dim term As Byte
Dim nextrec As Range
Dim path As String
Dim fname As String


Sub SaveInvWord()

invno = Range("J2")
custname = Range("E7")
amt = Range("J22")
dt_issue = Range("J3")
term = Range("J5")
path = "C:\Users\Me\Documents\"
fname = invno & " - " & custname

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Documents.Open ("C:\Users\Me\Documents\Test.docx")
objWord.Visible = True

objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=path & fname

Set nextrec = Sheet3.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

I'm new to VBA so I've tried fields.delete but I don't think I've got the syntax correct. Any explanation on how and what code to use would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please update OP to show copy / paste code.

Comment: There is no copy and paste code, the table is already copied and pasted into the document. The file opens a template doc with everything in and saves a new version. I need the link to be deleted in the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Check the field type and unlink `wdFieldLink` field.

```vb
Private Sub Unlink()
    Dim objWord As Object
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Documents.Open ("C:\Users\Me\Documents\Test.docx")
    Dim objLink As Object 'Field
    For Each objLink In objWord.ActiveDocument.Fields
        If objLink.Type = wdFieldLink Then
            objLink.Unlink
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Please ref to Microsoft document:

> [Field.Type property (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.field.type?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)